# Who were the people who loaded the data into his brain?

Tags: plot-explanation, johnny-mnemonic

In the beginning of Johnny Mnemonic, who were the people who loaded the information into his brain? Were they from Pharmokon? And if they were, who broke in and shot up the place? I thought they were from Pharmokon. Can anybody clear this up?

Comment: Somebody tag this with william-gibson and keanu-reeves.

Comment: Those tags are not appropriate here.

Comment: @leeand00 Yeah...no, please don't.

Answer (score 1):

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Mnemonic_(film)) has most of the answers,

The intended recipients of the data:

> Jane takes Johnny to meet her friend and street doctor Spider who had installed Jane's implants. In discussions, Spider reveals he and his allies at a local clinic were to be the recipients of Johnny's data.

Who attacked and shot up the place:

> After uploading their data, the group is massacred by **Yakuza**, but Johnny manages to escape with a portion of the encryption password.

Why?

> Johnny returns to Newark and soon finds that two groups are after the data he carries. One is the international pharmacological company, Pharmakom, led by its United States executive, Takahashi, who believes the data to be critical to the company's interests. The other is the Yakuza guided by Shinji, who wishes to deny this information to Takahashi and claim it for themselves.

What is the data:

> Supposedly Pharmakom's unpublished cure for "nerve attenuation syndrome", a plague ravaging mankind, due to the over-reliance on technology, and causing political strife.